# Continuously monitor a socket in Tornado Python framework

Tags: python, tornado

I am using Tornado and I want to monitor a socket continuously for notifications from a DB server. My application so far looks like this:

```
import functools
import tornado
import tornado.httpserver
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [(r"/", MyHandler),]
        super(Application, self).__init__(handlers)
        fd = get_socket_file_descriptor()
        callback = functools.partial(self.my_callback)
        io_loop = IOLoop.current()
        io_loop.add_handler(fd, callback, io_loop.READ)

    def my_callback(self, fd, events):
        # do something
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

My problem is this as soon as there is activity on the socket, the callback is called infinitely. I want the IOLoop to handle the call back and go back to listening on to the file descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IOLoop` will call your handler repeatedly as long as there is data to be read. Your callback must consume all the data in the socket to allow it to become idle again.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback must call `io_loop.remove_handler(fd)`. But consider connecting an `IOStream` to the file descriptor for a much more convenient and higher-level interface. You'd attach a callback to `IOStream.read_bytes`:

http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/iostream.html#tornado.iostream.BaseIOStream.read_bytes

Consider passing `partial=True` or a `streaming_callback` if you don't know what message length to expect, or use `read_bytes` with a `length` argument, or `read_until_regex` if you have some knowledge of when the end of the message will be.

Comment: Ok. Does that mean in order to monitor it after the callback is handled, do I have to call add_handler from the callback again? Also I will add code to consume the data as suggested by Ben.